# Sequelize produces invalid query "model.id AS model.id"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Here is the sequelize call I'm making to count favorites along with my model:

```
Model.findAll({

    group: [ 'model.id', 'favorites.id' ],
    attributes: [
        '*',
        [ Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('favorites.id')), 'favorites_count' ]
    ],
    include: [
        { attributes: [], model: Favorite },
    ]

});
```

Here's the query it produces:

```
SELECT
    model.id,
    model.*,
    count(favorites.id) AS favorites_count,
    favorites.id AS favorites.id # Invalid!
FROM models AS model ...
```

Here's the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: SELECT model.*, favorites.id AS favorites.id, ...
                                                  ^
```

Because `favorites.id` is not a valid AS alias. Why does Sequelize produce this
invalid alias and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent it - sequelize needs to alias the column. The query becomes invalid because you have set `quoteIdentifiers` to false. The query sequelize wants is `"favorites"."id" AS "favorites.id"`

Why is sequelize doing such a "stupid" thing you might say. Well lets take an example:

```
SELECT "model"."id", "favorites"."id" ...
```

This produces the following result set:

```
[{ id: 42 }]
```

Because the two columns have the same name, they override each other so only one of the columns is returned. So we need to alias the favorites column so we get

```
[{ id: 42, 'favorites.id': 87 }]
```

Comment: Discussion of joins with overlapping column names in pg https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/733